# Why am I getting damaged through a yellow lightning bolt?

Tags: warhammer-40k-inquisitor-martyr

I've recently begun playing *Warhammer 40000: Inquisitor – Martyr*, and noticed that for a reason unbeknownst to me, random enemies damage me through a yellow lightning bolt.

I've taken a screenshot here:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, there is a yellow lightning bolt between me and the Goreforged Enforcer, which deals *way* more damage than his gun, and I can't for the life of me figure out what it is, why it is happening and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a ranged attack based on Heat element.
I've seen other enemies using that "bolt" attack (usually red tinted) and even green (based on Poison?), and it seems impossible to avoid at close distance.

The only way to not being damaged is to stay as far as you can from that guy.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this the first time today after 100+ hours on the game and found only this page when searching for it, so I'll drop the answer for others landing here in the pursuit of knowledge.

The yellow bolt or flame is reflected damage.

Either you have some item that grants this effect or on high stake levels with  Empyrean Seals and Tarot Cards active sometime enemies get this effect.

You can see the effect here in this video about a Character Build that focuses on this trait